# How are the security groups injected in an image in OpenStack?

Tags: security, groups, openstack

I have been using OpenStack for some time and was just wondering how the security groups are injected in an image file.

I browsed on the internet but I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

They are not. This is implemented using `iptables` on the host level. Has nothing to do with the image file.